# Is it possible to open an image in Windows Phone 7 pictures application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application that loads image data from a web service. I want to allow the user to view the images in a similar UI than the phone's Pictures application provides (zoom in/out) etc. Is it possible to open my image data in the Pictures application or do I need to implement my own viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the image to the phone to view it with the pictures hub. So I would implement my own viewer. It's easy with the Silverlight Toolkit